# Can the first zombie player spawn the second zombie player's zombies?

Tags: last-night-on-earth

With the card "There's too many", in a two zombie player game, can zombie player 1 spawn zombie player 2's zombies if their remaining figures are out or are they forced to move the existing ones already on the board?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

According to [the rules](http://www.flyingfrog.net/lastnightonearth/pdf/LNOE_Rulebook_web.pdf):

> If there are two Zombie Players, each of them has a separate Zombie Pool of 7 Zombies each. One player takes all the Green Zombies, the other all of the Brown Zombies. **Players may never use Zombies from the other player's pool** (only their own color of Zombie).

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't matter if you could, since you are only allowed to place zombies if you roll **higher** than the number of zombies you personally control.

The [rules state](http://www.flyingfrog.net/lastnightonearth/pdf/LNOE_Rulebook_web.pdf) the following:

> **Place Starting Zombies** -  The Zombie Player starts the game with 2d6 Zombies on the board (**or 1d6 each if there are two Zombie Players**). Place the rolled number of Zombies on the board from your Zombie Pool. [...] If there are two Zombie Players, they are only limited in this way by **their own color** of Zombie (that is, the two players may double up Zombies on a Spawning Pit before each pit has a Zombie on it). (page 8)
>
> **3) Roll To Spawn New Zombies** - [...] If there are two Zombie players, each of them instead only rolls 1d6, needing to roll over the number of Zombies that **they personally control** on the board. (page 9)

Since each player starts with 6 zombies of their color, and you need to roll a 1d6 higher than the number you personally control, you cannot roller higher than '6'.

Comment: I beleive the card being asked about allows you to spawn additional zombies without havbing to roll for them